# Match until full stop

Tags: java, regex

Using below regex I'm attempting to match two groups, the first is all text until full stop is reached, the second is the number 0 or 1.

Here is the regex I'm trying : `"\\..+?(?=0|1)"`

Code :

```
    final String regex = "\\..+?(?=0|1)";

    final String string = "this is a test 123. 1";

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    }
```

prints : `.`

How to instead match `this is a test 123.` in `group(0)` and `1` in `group(1)` ?

Comment: Is there a certain reason you want the matches to be in groups 0 and 1, as 0 is the whole match? `[^.]*.(?=\\s*([01]))`

Comment: Following @SebastianProske's comment `^[^.]*.(?=[^01]*(.))`

Comment: regex must be (.*?\.).*?([10])

Comment: From what I see only [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52987463/3832970) provides a solution that yields what you need, the sentence (with a dot at the end) and the number in Groups 0 and 1. Have you had time to check? Also, if you have any doubts, please let know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Pattern` is not going to fit your requirements.

Here's what your `Pattern` parses for right now:

```
| literal dot
|  | followed by any 1+ sequence reluctantly quantified
|  |  | followed by non-capturing 1 or 2
|  |  | 
\\..+?(?=0|1)
```

By definition, non-capturing constructs cannot be back-referenced (i.e. you can never fetch their values by invoking `Matcher#group`).

And here's a simple example of what you way want instead:

```
String test = "this is a test 123. 1";
//                           | group 1: any 1+ char sequence reluctantly quantified, 
//                           |     | followed by a dot, non-capturing here
//                           |     |
//                           |     |     | any character reluctantly quantified
//                           |     |     | (here, your whitespace)
//                           |     |     |  | group 2: 1 or 2
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.+?)(?=\\.).*?([01])");
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("Group 1: %s%nGroup 2: %s%n", m.group(1), m.group(2));
}
```

**Output**

```
Group 1: this is a test 123
Group 2: 1
```

**Notes**

- Group `0` always represents the whole match.
- In other words, the user-defined numbered groups (defined by content enclosed in parenthesis in the pattern) start at index `1`.
- See **Groups and capturing** section [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).
- It seems your requirements for parsing the final `0` / `1` digit are a bit lax. You may want to ask yourself whether this digit is going to be "isolated", e.g. surrounded by non-alnum characters, or possibly part of a larger digit sequence, etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following regex:

```
final String regex = ".*\\.(?=\\s*([01]))";
final String string = "this is a test 123. 1";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/v1Ue2o).

**Pattern details**

- `.*\.` - (this will be Group 0 value) any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, up to the last `.` (and including it)
- `(?=\\s*([01]))` - a positive lookahead that requires 0+ whitespaces and then `1` or `0` (that are captured into Group 1) immediately to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 1):

Is the number always going to be `0` or `1` at the end?

Does it need to be a regex?

```
int fullStop = string.indexOf(".");
if (fullStop != -1) {
    System.out.println(string.substring(0, fullStop));
    System.out.println(string.substring(fullStop + 1).trim());
}
```

**Output:**

> this is a test 123
>
> 1

Answer (score 0):

Try regex `(.*?\.)(.*?[10])` and capture group 1 and 2

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/VcGMvx/1)